# mysql select id and name from other table and join query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 table named projects and tasks

in projects table i have:

```
id   name
---------
1    some
```

in tasks table i have:

```
id   name   project_id
----------------------
1    some        1
```

Now,how can i select * from task table and get the 'name' from projects table by 'project_id' in table tasks?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select task.id, task.name, proj.id, proj.name
from tasks task left join projects proj on proj.id=task.project_id;
```

Using [left join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) ensures you get something even if there is no record in the projects table. If you want to ensure coherency, you may do

```
select task.id, task.name, proj.id, proj.name
from tasks task, projects proj
where proj.id=task.project_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.*, p.[name] FROM tasks t
INNER JOIN projects p
ON t.project_id = p.[id]
WHERE t.project_id = ____
```

You fill in *_* with the project_id you want