# combine 2 tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Table: **team**

```
id | name
---------
1  | team a
2  | team b
3  | team c
```

Table: **event**

home & away are foreign key of **team**

```
id | home | away
----------------
1  |  2   |  3
2  |  1   |  2
3  |  3   |  1
```

**What I want to get:**

```
id | home   | away
------------------
 1 | team b | team c
 2 | team a | team b
 3 | team c | team a
```

Can anyone please teach me how to write the query to get the latest table based on the structure of this 2 tables. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652876/mysql-select-id-and-name-from-other-table-and-join-query

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of a question, but that is not the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join twice:

```
select e.id, th.name as home, ta.name as away
from event e join
     team th
     on e.home = th.id join
     team ta
     on e.away = ta.id;
```

Note that the two instances of `team` in the `from` clause have different table aliases.  That makes it possible to distinguish between those references when referencing columns.