# Trying to make query unique to each account as they log in with php

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble making an adjustment to my query. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT tt.unit_id, tt.latitude, tt.longitude
FROM AA55 tt
INNER JOIN
(SELECT unit_id, MAX(entry_id) AS MaxEntryID
FROM AA55
GROUP BY unit_id) groupedtt 
ON tt.unit_id = groupedtt.unit_id 
AND tt.entry_id = groupedtt.MaxEntryID;
```

This displays the most recent versions of each unique device along with its lat/lng. I am trying to add to it the ability to only show the devices where a user_id from a table called device_link is selected. So, if someone logs into their account, I only want the query to pull the devices that are linked to their account. Any ideas?

Comment: So you need to join that table with the user ID's and add a `WHERE` part to your query limiting on the desired user ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select id and name from other table and join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652876/mysql-select-id-and-name-from-other-table-and-join-query)

Comment: Sorry, that might not have been the best existing answer I found. Think I pasted wrong link. Think it sort of covers it though. i.e. has been asked. Suppose let us know if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would help to see something like an ER diagram for the relationships between the tables. Basically something like this though:

```
SELECT 
  tt.unit_id, 
  tt.latitude, 
  tt.longitude
FROM AA55 tt
LEFT JOIN device_link AS dl ON dl.id = unit_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT unit_id, MAX(entry_id) AS MaxEntryID FROM AA55 GROUP BY unit_id) AS groupedtt 
    ON tt.unit_id = groupedtt.unit_id 
    AND tt.entry_id = groupedtt.MaxEntryID
WHERE dl.user_id = ?;
```

Like I said in the comment, you need to join on unit/device/thingy ID and then put a constraint on the user ID.