# SELECT Query Depends another

Tags: php, mysql

I've two tables that are: list_event and cities

In list_event has a column name 'cities'. 
I want to take 'cities' value and search in 'cities' table to get city name.

I don't know logic to do that and I haven't code in this moment, .

```
SELECT * FROM list_event ORDER BY id_event DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: JOIN? `list_events INNER JOIN cities ON list_events.cities ON cities.name`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Hi, please take a look at [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13652876/3753055) (check out the question before) and tell me if it helps understand the join concept.

Comment: What are the attributes in Cities table.

Comment: I'll search and try with INNER JOIN !

Comment: @AnwarNairi thanks, i'll see

Comment: SELECT list_event.nome, municipio.Nome FROM list_event INNER JOIN municipio ON cities=Municipio.Nome

Comment: With this code above, my code doesn't run but I think is right

Comment: Solved: SELECT list_event.nome, Municipio.Nome FROM list_event INNER JOIN municipio ON list_event.cities = Municipio.Codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join here

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Probably in your case

```
SELECT list_event.event, cities.cityName FROM list_event LEFT JOIN cities ON list_event.city_value=cities.city_value;
```

Comment: I want to take all 'list_event' columns AND change cities value (number) to string (cities name)

Comment: I have used supposed column names. Change it according to your database